# SQL Server - ORA Data Flow Task with High Data Volume

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012

In my SSIS package I am trying to move data from SQL Server to Oracle using a Data Flow. The volume of data is high (4,000,000+ rows with around 25 columns) and I am getting an error sometimes. In case it runs successfully, it runs for a very long time.

> OnError,,,PACKAGENAME,{4B45B43D-6F87-4B12-8B69-03954EF13CCA},,09/09/2014
>   7:10:44 PM,09/09/2014 7:10:44 PM,-1071636471,0x,SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "ROW-00060: Internal error:
>   [dainsert,16]孬u".

I have googled it and found some people suggesting Attunity connector. A few have tried out a third party Oracle connector that boasts of a lot of acceleration in the data flow. Are there any other solutions? Anybody who has successfully implemented a SQL Server-to-ORA DFT with a high data volume successfully ?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that, Microsoft connectors to Oracle by Attunity works only with Enterprise and Developer Editions of SSIS/MS SQL Server suite. If you have installed Standard Edition, then no chance on any destination components as the oracle provider is not supported for fast load options. I'm also struggling with terabytes of data load to oracle but running in chunks of millions.

Answer (score 1):

I was initially using OLE DB Destination when I was getting that same error.  I used ADO NET Destination instead and my data loaded successfully from SQL server to Oracle database.

SSIS.Pipeline: "component "ADO NET Destination" (49)" wrote 76506582 rows.

Answer (score 0):

When loading data into Oracle using SSIS use of 'Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity' can improve the performances. Although I do not have the statistics, my team has implemented this successfully in a project.

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to solve the issue. My issue was related to bitness.**

For large tables, I used SSIS Import and Export Wizard 64 Bit to save the packages on dtsx format. However, I was getting the subject mentioned error when executing the package in SSIS Execute Package Utility at the point of insertion of lakhs of record in destination Oracle table.

After search I found that SSIS Execute Package Utility runs in 32 Bit by default and that was the root cause of issue.

To solve the same, I executed the package from command line using 64 bit DTExec.exe that was installed under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn. I used below command to run my package and 40lakh records were loaded successfully into destination Oracle DB that was initially failing at around 3Lakh records using SSIS Execute Package Utility (DTExecUI.exe):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn> DTExec.exe /FILE "\"F:\SQLtoOracle\QC_MASTER_FINAL\QC_MASTER_FINAL_Batch2.dtsx\"" /CONNECTION DestinationConnectionOLEDB;"\"Data Source=PRIMARY;User ID=*******;Password=*******;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;\"" /CONNECTION SourceConnectionOLEDB;"\"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=QC_MASTER_FINAL;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;\""  /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW
```